# How can I return a string as a template class in C++?

Tags: c++, string, templates

I want to write a **template< class T > T string_to_T(const string& s)** function that switches a string to a tempate T. T can be int/double/string and I write one as below:

```
template<class T> T Config::string_to_T(const string& s){
    T t;
    bool at_in = false;

    istringstream ist(s);
    ist >> t;

    return t;
}
```

But when there is a blank space in the string, it doesn't work. **e.g. string = '1 2 3 4'**, returned t is **string** type and equals 4. How can I change to meet my need?

Comment: Considering your example, what are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want to get a string type and the value equals "1 2 3 4"

Comment: So what's the purpose of a function that converts string "1 2 3 4" to string "1 2 3 4"?

Comment: when s = "1 2 3 4", I want return "1 2 3 4", but when s = "1", I want return int 1, not a string.

Comment: Not possible. You can't return two types.

Comment: You simply couldn't call a function like this - how would you store the return if you don't know its type? You need a variant return type and some logic.

Comment: Types exist at compile time. Values exist at run time. Compile time happens before run time. You cannot have a value influence a type, because an event that happens later in time cannot influence an event that happens earlier.

Comment: You are right, the question is how could I let istringstream ist know string("1 2 3 4") must return as a string, not a int value, because there are blank spaces in the string.

Comment: Are you looking for [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) ?

Comment: @xiaoyi, I am not trying to return two types of values at the same time, and I just want to return the value that should be.return string("1") as a int 1, return string("1 2 3 4") as a string, since there are blank spaces in it

Comment: @AlexandreC. mostly, but the return type is decided implicitly by the string s's form

Comment: @Mat this is a class function, and template T's type will be dicided by the return value.

Comment: Nope, that won't happen. Type deduction only applies to parameters, not return values.

Comment: @Mat It's perfectly possible to have the behavior as if type deduction applied to return values, by returning a proxy with the appropriate conversion operators.  It's also possible to return a `boost::variant`, and deffer the choice of type until later.  Before recommending either of these solutions, however, I'd like to see his use case.  Circumventing the C++ type system is _usually_ not a good idea.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I mentioned variant return types before. And type deduction does not apply to return types. You can whatever you want to simulate that, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `boost::lexical_cast`.  Basically, you need to specialize
for the cases where `>>` doesn't do what you want.  If you want
`string_to_T<std::string>` to be a no-op, for example, you write
a specialization:

```
template<>
std::string
string_to_T<std::string>( std::string const& s )
{
    return s;
}
```

For more complicated cases, you can forward to a functional
object, and use partial specialization, but for the case you 
describe, this shouldn't be necessary.

While you're at it, you should probably think about error
handling.  What happens if you call `string_to_T<int>`, and the
input is "abcd"?  For that matter, if you call
`string_to_T<int>` with `"1 2 3 4"`, should the results be 1, or
an error?

### EDIT:

Having seen more of the comments to your question: you cannot
change the return type at runtime (with certain very limited
exceptions when returning a reference or a pointer within a
class hierarchy).  C++ is a statically typed language, every
expression has a distinct type, determined at compile time.
Supposing you could return two different types, how would you
use the function, and how could the compiler detect the type
errors it is required to detecte.  The closest you can come is
to return some sort of proxy, with implicit conversions to the
various types, but the type you convert to would still be
statically determined, according to what you do with the
results: assign it to an `int`, and it will convert to an `int`,
regardless of the contents of the string.

This type safety is a feature; detecting errors at compile time
makes the code far more robust and sure than deferring the error
detection to runtime.  If you can do without this safety
(non-critical application), and need the added flexibility of
runtime typing, C++ is not the right language; you should be
using something like Python.

### EDIT 2:

In response to your comment, the solution would seem to be
something along the lines of:

```
class ToStringHelper
{
    std::string myValue;
public:
    ToStringHelper( std::string const& value )
        : myValue( value )
    {
    }
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return myValue;
    }
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        std::istringstream cvt( myValue );
        T results;
        cvt >> results;
        //  Error checking here...
        return results;
    }
};

ToStringHelper
string_to_T( std::string const& s )
{
    return ToStringHelper( s );
}
```

I use this exact pattern for configuration data (with errors
triggering an exception).

Comment: template T's type will be decided by the calling a function's argument, such as`int port, port = conf.Read("port", port);` and Read() will return the port value as a int type, `return string_to_T<T>( p->second );`.    It's the same `string ip, ip = conf.Read("ip", ip);` will get a string type value returned

Comment: If the type is determined by the calling context (what you do with the return value), then the solution is easy.  Just return a proxy.  I'll edit my response to add a simple example.

Comment: A question, when `myValue` equals to `"1 2 3 4"`,`cvt >> results`; only return 1 to results, doesn't it?

Comment: It depends of the type of T. For `int`, probably, but for `string` it will return `"1 2 3 4"`.

Comment: @foool Because that is how `>>` is defined.  White space is a separator; it's ignored at the start, and it terminates the input.  If that definition doesn't suit your needs, then you can't use `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you showed is doing a conversion from `std::string` to `T`. You specify `T` at compile time, you *cannot* change it at runtime.

If you want the type to depend on the value, you can use a Variant. See [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html) for example (if you're working with Qt, there is QVariant). You can also use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html) ([difference between Variant and Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)). For the conversion you might want to use [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html). You will probably need to specify yourself that `"1" -> 1` and `"1 2 3 4" - > "1 2 3 4"` in the variant/any. Be aware that all these functions will need you to add some code to handle the types. With variants, you can use [visitors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html), a really powerful method to handle different types in variants.

Comment: Using `boost::variant` really just defers the issue.  C++ is statically typed, and at some point, he's going to have to declare a variable with a specific type to handle the returned value.  There are some very specific cases where `boost::variant` is useful, but the question is such that it makes me think that this is more a case of the original poster not understanding the C++ type system, rather than one of the specific cases.  It would be interesting to see his use case, so we could offer a real solution.

Comment: Yep, forgot to said that it will need some logic. Fixed. He still can use visitors.

Comment: There's no problem with your solution.  It's the appropriate solution for some problems.  At the time, it wasn't clear what problem he was trying to solve.  (His later comments explain this somewhat, and suggest that a proxy is the correct solution, not `boost::variant`.  But his original posting certainly didn't suggest this.)

Answer (score 0):

Code to Convert any datatype to string:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
string toString(const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}


int main(void)
{


    string str;

    cout<<"Convert any datatype to string\n\n\n";

    int i=1234;
    str=toString(i );
    cout<<"int i= "<<str<<"\n";


  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to change any type to string type, and I just want to change `string("122")` to `int(122)`, `string("123.2")` to 'double(123.2)' and  `string("new world")` to `string("new wolrd")`

Comment: @foool At how do you define the variable to which you assign the results?

Comment: `int i = conf.Read("key", i)`, `Read()`is defined as`template<class T> T Config::Read(const string& key, const T& value)const` will get the value from a map, and `return string_to_T<T>( p->second );` . Actually T is defined by the argument `i` in this case